# How to perform operations on 'this' element using event delegation in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to perform a function on each file input field in my code. You can see the html and function below.

```
<tbody class="gal_picture_fields">
  <tr class="nested-fields">      
    <td>
      <input type="file"> 
    </td>
    <td class="thumb">
    </td>
  <tr class="nested-fields">      
    <td>
      <input type="file"> 
    </td>
    <td class="thumb">
    </td>
  <tr class="nested-fields">      
    <td>
      <input type="file"> 
    </td>
    <td class="thumb">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the function

```
function editPicPreview() {
  $(".gal_picture_fields").on('change', '.nested-fields td input[type=file]', function addFile(e) {    
    thumbContainer = $(this).closest('td').siblings('.thumb');
    return thumbContainer
  })
}
```

I want to have the function fire for the specified element that the event occurred on so if it fires on the third element have the function return that. If I use `$(this)` it returns the first `input` field not the third element where the event occurred on. How can I achieve this?

Sorry I tried to make a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/byh022Lx/36/

**UPDATE Original Code**

```
function editPicPreview() {
  $(".gal_picture_fields").on('change', '.nested-fields td input[type=file]', function addFile(e) {
    var file, thumbContainer, url;
    file = e.target.files[0]; /* Uses event delegation, returns FileList object [0] eg. for each file input field when uploaded each time */
    url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    thumbContainer = $(this).closest('td').siblings('.thumb');
    var img = new Image();  
      img.onload = function() {  
      var width = img.naturalWidth;
      var height = img.naturalHeight;
      if (height < 200) { return }
      var ratio = width / height;   
      var newheight = 200
      var newwidth = ratio * 200
      img.width = newwidth
      img.height = newheight            
      }
    img.src = url;
    return thumbContainer.append(img)
  });
};
```

Comment: *"If I use $(this) it returns the first input field not the third element where the event occurred on"* No, it doesn't. `this` in an event callback like that is the element the event passed through. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem with the code **in** the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Note that *returning* something from your event handler (other than `return false` which has special meaning) doesn't do anything. It's also not clear when/how you call `editPicPreview`. And beware of [*The Horrror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html); you'll want to declare `thumbContainer`.

Comment: Works fine when you actually put `<tbody>` inside a `<table>`. https://jsfiddle.net/byh022Lx/38/ It is invalid to put `<tbody>` in any other element like `<body>` and what is being rendered does not include the rows or cells as a result

Comment: @TJ Crowder. Thanks for that info. I know just returning it to show I want that element. I will look at this as I can see that using what @charlietfl said in my fiddle it works and thats what it says on the jquery website but my code keeps inserting my image to the first `td.thumb` not the one that my table refers to and you think it would insert the image in the td element I have selected.

Comment: Something must be different than what is shown in your actual code then

Comment: @LeeEather: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Again, please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I will update with my original code but I tried to take out the mess but perhaps I should have made the fiddle a bit better I thought I wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Updated code works fine also in same fiddle with `<table>`

Comment: Your right. Well im a bit confused I cant think why this isn't working I copied it directly from my app. All I can say is is the image pops up in the first `td.thumb` no matter what input I load a img.

Comment: The problem here is that when you see the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/byh022Lx/43/ I am using `<label for="my_input">Choose File</label>` and as this markup is rendered each time by a partial each input has the same `id`. So I do not know exactly atm but my function is finding this label the first time for the first element. And yes I know I DIDNT include it in my original question, lesson, learned!

Comment: Sorry to be precise, the label `for` attr points to a element in a form so I am guessing at the moment that the form searches from top to bottom and as it finds a match on the first element every input is being matched. I think the trick is to wrap the input in the label rather than use the `for` attr and use css to position it. I will add a answer once I get it working right. Thanks guys.